# Асинхронная загрузка в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Можно ли подгрузить следующую сцену в текущей, но не запускать её? К Примеру, метод SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync() запускает сцену сразу после загрузки.

Answer (score 3):

До загрузки сцены выставьте флаг [`allowSceneActivation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-allowSceneActivation.html) в `false` и не будет моментально запускаться.

Comment: Да, кстати, вариант, забыл про него. Еще там проблема есть с запуском AsyncLoad в Awake, он игнорит allowSceneActivation. Поэтому делайте в Start-Update. https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/loadsceneasync-allowsceneactivation-flag-is-ignored-in-awake

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но я всё-таки решил использовать лучше загрузочный экран